Switching camera format
I often have more than one camera in my scene. And I often want one to use landscape format and the other portrait. I've been switching by hand the ResolutionX and Y parameters in the Output Format panel when I change cameras. There must be an easier way!

This feature is missing in blender, but there is an addon that should do what you want
https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/per-camera-resolution/

Maybe you can save some cameras as assets?
